# Uninstall Clearcase (and mvfs) on AIX system?

Tags: clearcase, aix

How to uninstall everything: **mvfs**, all services, albd, all files and folders?

For information a cleartool hostinfo -properties gives:

ClearCase 8.0.1.4 (AIX 1 7)

Scaling factor to initialize MVFS cache sizes: 24

MVFS cache sizes:

Free mnodes: 13967

Free mnodes for cleartext: 13967

File names: 20000

Directory names: 5000

Names not found: 20000

RPC handles: 240

Initial mnode table size: 63488

Blocks per directory: 6

Minimum free mnodes: 12570

Minimum free mnodes for cleartext: 13167

Cleartext idle lifetime: 259200

VOB hash table size: 8192

Cleartext hash table size: 2048

DNC hash table size: 4507

Thread hash table size: 511

Process hash table size: 511

Installed product: MultiSite version 8.0.1.1 (Fri Sep 20 16:09:14 EDT 2013) (8.0.1.01.00_2013C.FCS)

Installed product: MultiSite version 8.0.1.2 (Wed Dec 11 16:09:14 EDT 2013) (8.0.1.02.00_2013D.FCS)

Installed product: MultiSite version 8.0.1.3 (Wed Mar 19 00:31:17 EST 2014) (8.0.1.03.00_2014A.FCS)

Installed product: MultiSite version 8.0.1.3-iFix01 (Tue Apr 22 18:14:02 EDT 2014) (8.0.1.03.01_2014A.1.FCS)

Installed product: MultiSite version 8.0.1.04 (Wed Jun 11 00:31:23 EDT 2014) (8.0.1.04.00_2014B.D140610)

Installed product: ClearCase version 8.0.1.1 (Fri Sep 20 16:09:14 EDT 2013) (8.0.1.01.00_2013C.FCS)

Installed product: ClearCase version 8.0.1.2 (Wed Dec 11 16:09:14 EDT 2013) (8.0.1.02.00_2013D.FCS)

Installed product: ClearCase version 8.0.1.3 (Wed Mar 19 00:31:17 EST 2014) (8.0.1.03.00_2014A.FCS)

Installed product: ClearCase version 8.0.1.3-iFix01 (Tue Apr 22 18:14:02 EDT 2014) (8.0.1.03.01_2014A.1.FCS)

Installed product: ClearCase version 8.0.1.04 (Wed Jun 11 00:31:23 EDT 2014) (8.0.1.04.00_2014B.D140610)

Answer (score 2):

This was installed via IBM installation Manager (IM), are you unable to uninstall it via Installation Manager? Most people try to use the GUI interface to IM, but if

- there isn't enough XWindows installed, or
- some of the GUI libraries are the wrong versions for the Eclipse shell to start, or
- You are using telnet (Odd, but you *can*) or SSH without X forwarding,

you may get some "helpful" error messages. You can use the "imcl" command to do this from a terminal session by (note these paths are DEFAULT, and may not match your setup as a result) running:

```
/opt/IBM/InstallationManager/eclipse/tools/imcl -c
```

And following the prompts to remove that version of ClearCase. I recall CC 8.0.1 allows removal on the command line for this very reason. (Installing, upgrading, and uninstalling on Unix hosts without requiring X or X-forwards.)